# How to make color of object in unity 100% opaque

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, renderer

I set color alpha to 1.0f, i set shader to transparent/diffuse

```
color = new Color(255/255f, 0/255f, 0/255f, 1f) //unity scales color to 1 AFAIK
go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.shader = Shader.Find("Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Diffuse");
```

But i can still see original texture behind the red color. How can i paint it red whole, so i won't see the original texture?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you set the material texture to null? Like this ->

go.GetComponent().materials[1].mainTexture = null;

Comment: Thanks this worked! But I have one question, maybe its stupid. Does the color interfere with "default color" of the object like it did with the texture that was there before?

Still it doesn't make too much sense that the texture was visible when i set the texture color alpha to 100%. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not really sure but i think the default color only dye the texture.

Comment: @Filip12345 If the texture can be null, you don't need a shader that has such requirement. Use one of the default shaders that give you a solid color outright.

Comment: @Filip12345 Two things: accessing the material will automatically clone it for that object (use `sharedMaterial` if you don't want to clone it). The reason this works is because no texture is assumed to be all white by the shader.

Comment: @XenoRo I thought standard shader would do that but he did not, he just didnt respond to alpha at all - always same level of transparency.

Comment: @Draco18s so i had two materials there and that was the reason for seeing original texture as well?

Comment: @Filip12345 What? No really, what? Two materials doesn't make any sense (yes, you can have more than one, but it does a specific thing that is not what you're asking about). The reason you "still see the texture" is because the color is *multiplied* with the color of the texture. If the texture is black, no matter what you multiply it with, it will still be black.

Comment: @Draco18s Oh thanks now it makes more sense. I dont see how your original comment was related to the problem though. (no offense meant, just curious).

I just tried shared material, it changed texture of all siblings objects as well.

Comment: @Filip12345 It is likely you DO want `material`, my comment was in regards to the fact that Unity automatically does some things behind the scenes that in *some* situations is undesirable and that you should be aware of it. Say you want to change two objects out of four. Using `material` you end up with two cloned materials that are exactly identical, but not the same object!  If you instead created a second material in your assets folder and programmatically assigned it to your object, you would not have that problem.